# Accessing the internet with knitr

Tags: google-maps, knitr, ggmap

When I run some code to draw a map using ggmap, in Rstudio it runs fine. When I run it using knitr it fails with the following error message:-

> Error in download.file(url, destfile = destfile, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :
>     cannot open URL 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=-40.851253,172.799669&zoom=19&size=%20640x640&scale=%202&maptype=hybrid&sensor=false'
>   Calls:  ... eval -> eval -> get_map -> get_googlemap -> download.file
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In download.file(url, destfile = destfile, quiet = !messaging, mode = "wb") :
>     unable to connect to 'maps.googleapis.com' on port 80.
>   Execution halted

I am sure this is due to the way our network is set up, probably around permissions,  but is anyone able to give me any clues as to how knitr would try to access the internet to download a map so I may be able to find a way though our firewall.

Code added but it works fine except through our network.

````
---
title: "Drawing a map"
author: "Alasdair Noble"
output: word_document
---




To draw a map

```{r echo=TRUE, warning=FALSE ,  results='markup', comment="",message=FALSE }
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(GGally)
library(plyr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggmap)
library(ggthemes)

```




```{r echo=TRUE, warning=FALSE ,  results='markup', comment="", message=FALSE }

Btrcup <- get_map(location=c(lon=171.799669, lat=-42.851253),zoom=19,      maptype="hybrid")
Btrcupmap <- ggmap(Btrcup)

Btrcupmap

```
````

Comment: Cannot reproduce your error message. The document is knitted correctly on my machine. Are you sure that the posted code throws the error message from the question on your machine? (Maybe you accidentially removed some relevant code before posting it.)

Comment: As I said in the question I know that the code works fine, it works if I take it home, it works if I take my work computer off our network and log in to a public wifi. It doesn't work on our network at work and my question was about how knitr accesses the internet to try to give our IT support some clues as to what the problem is. It seems that knitr is different in this respect to just running the code in RStudio which again works fine.