# R: 'unable to connect to 'maps.googleapis.com' on port 80' inside foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach, ggmap

I'm new to stackoverflow, so please correct me if I make any major mistakes.

As a part of a bigger project I have a function that requests routes from Google and calculates the driving time, I do this with the package ggmap. This worked perfectly fine until I tried to speed things up on other parts of the project and needed to call the driving time function within a foreach loop. In the loop, when I use `%dopar%` it throws this error:

```
unable to connect to 'maps.googleapis.com' on port 80.
```

Does anyone know, where this error comes from and how it can be fixed?

I managed to produce a small example that shows the behaviour:

```
# necessary packages
library(ggmap)
library(doParallel)
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)

# some lines to test the function in a for and a foreach loop
Origins <- c("Bern","Biel","Thun","Spiez")
Destinations <- c("Biel","Thun","Spiez","Bern")
numRoutes = length(Origins)
# numCores = detectCores()
# I use only 1 core in testing to make sure that the debug-file is readable 
cl <- snow::makeCluster(1, outfile = "debug.txt")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

timesDoPar <-foreach(idx=1:numRoutes,
    .packages = c("ggmap")) %dopar% {
        getDrivingTime(Origins[idx], Destinations[idx])
    }

timesDo <-foreach(idx=1:numRoutes,
    .packages = c("ggmap")) %do% {
        getDrivingTime(Origins[idx], Destinations[idx])
    }

stopCluster(cl)
```

The function (with some extra for debugging):

```
getDrivingTime <- function(from, to){
    if (from == to){
        drivingTimeMin = 0
    } else{
        route_simple <- tryCatch({
            message("Trying to get route from Google")      
            route(from, to, structure = "route", mode = "driving", output = "simple")
        },
        error=function(cond) {
            message("Route throws an error:\nHere's the original error message:")
            message(cond)
        return(data.frame(minutes=0))
        },
        warning=function(cond) {
            message("Route throws a warning:\nHere's the original warning message:")
            message(cond)
            return(data.frame(minutes=0))
        },
        finally={      
            message(paste0("\nProcessed route: ", from, "; ", to, "\n\n"))
        })     

        drivingTimeMin = sum(route_simple$minutes, na.rm = TRUE)
    }  
    return(drivingTimeMin)
}
```

I'm aware that in this example it would make absolutely no sense to use parallel programming - especially with using only one core - but in the scope of the full project it is needed.

I couldn't find any useful information related to this except for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466608/accessing-the-internet-with-knitr), where the person asking suggests that the problem might be with the network in their company. I don't think that this is the case for me, since it works with `%do%`. I couldn't test it in another network yet, though.

(I'm working on Windows 7, using a portable version of R (R version 3.1.0) and R Studio (Version 0.98.501))

Comment: Just an overdue update: I'm now using the workaround to query all possible driving times and saving them in a data frame before entering the foreach loop. This is inefficient because not all possible routes will be used  and it has to be redone each time something in the coordinates of the destinations changes but at least it works.